# Whenever I call a method using an action[] array, it outputs 'System.Action[]' in the console app? - C# Console App

Tags: c#

I'm making a simple quiz game using arrays and I thought of using methods and putting them inside said arrays to call them whenever I want with the arrays. However, whenever I put the defined methods into arrays and try to call the array containing the methods, it just shows 'System.Action[]' in the console app?

```
//arrays
Action[] testThree = new Action[]
{ 
    () => testThreeQuestionOne(),
    () => testThreeQuestionTwo() 
};

string[] testThreeInput = new string[11];

//test three
Console.WriteLine("\n\n------------------Test III. Analysis.------------------");
for (k = 0; k < testThree.Length; k++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n" + (i + (j + (k + 1))) + ". " + testThree[k]);
    testThreeInput[k] = Console.ReadLine();                              
}

//methods
static void testThreeQuestionOne()
{
    string test3Question1 = "What is the output of:" +
        "Console.WriteLine(\"asd\");";
    Console.WriteLine(test3Question1);
};
static void testThreeQuestionTwo()
{
    string test3Question2 = "What is the output of: " +
        "Console.WriteLine(\"lol\");";
    Console.WriteLine(test3Question2);
};
```

I tried converting them into string methods, using a string[] instead, but it wouldn't work. I'm new to creating methods since I'm only a beginner so I don't have a single clue how to find solutions.

Comment: You never call anything, you're formatting the `Action` objects as strings. What you see is the output of the base `ToString()` method - the type of the object There's no such thing as a `string method`. Use `testThree[k]()` to actually call the action

Answer (score 1):

As @PanagiotisKanavos pointed out in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77572240/whenever-i-call-a-method-using-an-action-array-it-outputs-system-action-i/77574437#comment136755110_77572240), you are not actually calling any of the methods by passing `testThree[k]` as a parameter of `Console.WriteLine()`. In order to invoke the methods inside testThree, iterate over the array testThree[k] and call it adding parentheses `()`.

That is to say, replace the code inside your `for`loop:

```
Console.WriteLine("\n" + (i + (j + (k + 1))) + ". " + testThree[k]);
testThreeInput[k] = Console.ReadLine();
```

by

```
testThree[k]();
```

Also note that an `Action`:

> Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and does not return a value.

This means that if you use actions, you can't actually receive any result passed after invoking those actions, invoking them is a "fire and forget" thing.

Finally, you don't need to populate testThree using lambdas `() => testThreeQuestionOne()`, you can populate it directly using only the methods names:

```
var testThree = new Action[]
{
    testThreeQuestionOne,
    testThreeQuestionTwo,
};
```

All in all, the full program looks like this:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //arrays
        var testThree = new Action[]
        {
            testThreeQuestionOne,
            testThreeQuestionTwo,
        };

        string[] testThreeInput = new string[11];

        //test three

        int i = 0, j = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("\n\n------------------Test III. Analysis.------------------");
        for (int k = 0; k < testThree.Length; k++)
        {
            testThree[k]();
        }
    }

    //methods
    static void testThreeQuestionOne()
    {
        string test3Question1 = "What is the output of: " +
            "Console.WriteLine(\"asd\");";
        Console.WriteLine(test3Question1);
    }

    static void testThreeQuestionTwo()
    {
        string test3Question2 = "What is the output of: " +
            "Console.WriteLine(\"lol\");";
        Console.WriteLine(test3Question2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you can *probably* get away with using `string` instead of `Action` in the first place. But I'll set that aside for the moment and assume you have good reasons for this (ie: allowing more complicated questions).

So let's explain what's going on with the `Action` text on the Console.

We have this expression:

```
"\n" + (i + (j + (k + 1))) + ". " + testThree[k]
```

To evaluate this, the compiler eventually needs to work out the final `". " + testThree[k]` operation. Actually, the left hand side will already be more complicated, but the main thing to understand is you have a **string**, an addition operator, and the `testThree[k]` value, which evaluates as an `Action`.

So we have `string + Action`.

Since the left-hand side is a string and the right-hand side is not, the compiler needs to find a workable way to use the addition operator. To do that, it will treat the `Action` as an `Object`. The compiler will **NOT** resolve this by automatically calling the action method, especially since `Action` has a `void` return type.

When using `string` and `Object` with the addition operator, the result is determined by calling the basic `ToString()` method every type inherits. However, for *most types* (including `Action`), the result of this method is just *the name of the type*.

And thus we have the name of the type (`Action`) written to the console, while the action methods themselves *were never called*.

To resolve this, we do three things:

1. Use `Func<string>` instead of `Action`
2. Have the Funcs (and supporting methods) return their result instead of writing to the console on their  own
3. *Call the method*

```
//arrays
Func<string>[] testThree = new Func<string>[]
{ 
    () => testThreeQuestionOne(),
    () => testThreeQuestionTwo() 
};

string[] testThreeInput = new string[testThree.Length];

//test three
Console.WriteLine("\n\n------------------Test III. Analysis.------------------");
for (k = 0; k < testThree.Length; k++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n" + (i + (j + (k + 1))) + ". " + testThree[k]());
    testThreeInput[k] = Console.ReadLine();                              
}

//methods
static string testThreeQuestionOne()
{
    string test3Question1 = "What is the output of:" +
        "Console.WriteLine(\"asd\");";
    return test3Question1;
};
static string testThreeQuestionTwo()
{
    string test3Question2 = "What is the output of: " +
        "Console.WriteLine(\"lol\");";
    return test3Question2;
};
```

Alternatively you could leave the `Action[]` and methods unchanged, but update to the loop to call the method separate from writing the string:

```
for (k = 0; k < testThree.Length; k++)
{
    Console.Write("\n" + (i + (j + (k + 1))) + ". ");
    testThree[k]();
    testThreeInput[k] = Console.ReadLine();                              
}
```

---

But again, for preference, I'd do this if I could:

```
//arrays
string[] testThree = new string[]
{ 
    """What is the output of: Console.WriteLine("asd");""",
    """What is the output of: Console.WriteLine("lol");""" 
};

string[] testThreeInput = new string[testThree.Length];

//test three
Console.WriteLine("\n\n------------------Test III. Analysis.------------------");
for (k = 0; k < testThree.Length; k++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n" + (i + (j + (k + 1))) + ". " + testThree[k]);
    testThreeInput[k] = Console.ReadLine();                              
}
```

Comment: testThree[k](); did it for me. Thank you so much for the helpful comments!